# Going backwards with Symfony DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I'm using Symfony DomCrawler to parse my HTML. I'm reading articles on my website like this:

```
$domCrawler->filter('.post')->each(function (DomCrawler $post) {
    // ...
});
```

How can I walk through them backwards? I'd like to start from the post that is at the very bottom of the page and then go up.

Comment: You can add them to array, reverse this result array and then iterate over reversed array

Comment: That was my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `count` and `eq` functions. Do something like this.

```
for ($i = $nodes->count() - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
     $node = $nodes->eq($i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods of `Cralwer` to achieve what you want.

```
// Getting posts
$posts = $domCrawler->filter('.post');

// Reversing posts
if ($posts->count() > 1) {
    // Get reversed array of nodes
    $nodes = array_reverse((array) $posts->getIterator());
    // Clear current nodes
    $posts->clear();
    // Add the same nodes in reversed order
    $posts->addNodes($nodes);
}

$posts->each(function (DomCrawler $post) {
    // ...
});
```